# Method and Property chaining calls in Swift

Tags: swift, nsstring, nsnumberformatter, method-chaining

I have been trying to understand the concept of method chaining in programming but I'm a little confused. So far I was able to call multiple function from the same class by returning `self`.

Can some explain and possibly put a quick example on how you can call a method from one class and a property from a different class? I'm interested in the implementation.

For instance the following code demonstrates how the method `numberFromString()` from the `NSNumberFormatter`class is called then the property `doubleValue` from the `NSString` class is called on the same line.

```
var myString = "123"

var myDouble = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(myString)!.doubleValue
```

Can someone please help me understand this concept by putting a quick example similar to the above code.

Thanks

Comment: NSNumberFormatter's instance method numberFromString  will return NSNumber , and you are accessing its public doubleValue property. That is what is happening. Important thing you should keep in mind is that numberFromString actually returns an optional (NSNumber?) because not every string can be converted into number. So, in your case, the app will crash if something like "1a345" is passed. You should not use forced unwrapping like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doubleValue` in this case is being called on an instance of `NSNumber`, the return type of the `numberFromString:` method of `NSNumberFormatter`. `NSString` also has the same property.

```
var myString = "123"

var myNumber = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(myString)!

var myDouble = myNumber.doubleValue
```